# Sencha EXTJS4 - How to change the icon of the buttons ItemSelector

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How can i change the icons of the buttons in ItemSelector in Sencha extjs 4.[Screenshot for the ItemSelector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q80kl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change those icons, you have to override css classes:

```
.x-form-itemselector-top {
    background-image: url(images/itemselector/top.gif);
}

.x-form-itemselector-bottom {
    background-image: url(images/itemselector/bottom.gif);
}
```

In the background image use your custom image. This is only the up and bottom icon. You should search for the other css classes with Chrome Debugger for example.